# Ionic Applink not working for Redirection

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth, deep-linking

I am trying to build a feature where user gets an email verification link and on click it should open the app/ bring it to front. I am using ionic with cordova. I am trying to achieve this using the plugin `ionic-plugin-deeplinks`.

It works fine when I hit the url directly ex: "https://example.com/abc" directly from browser or email app but when I integrate it with OAuth as redirect URI it doesn't trigger the app open but rather tries to open it as website.

**Code and Setup:**

*Package.json*

*package version:*

```
   "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.24",
```

*plugin meta:*

```
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "com.company.app",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "example.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
      }
```

*config.xml:*

```
<platform name="android">
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

I have also uploaded the assetlinks.json to the website> .wellknown

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Please feel free to ask for any other specific details regarding the setup.

Thanks in advance